# Is it possible to show only a path on content tree and media library on Content Editor?

Tags: content-editor

I am planning to create a custom Content Editor view wherein Editors can only view a part of the `/sitecore/content tree` and `/sitecore/media library` tree. I am aware of how to configure it in the `Core DB` by creating a custom button and creating a link `/sitecore/shell/Applications/Content%20Editor.aspx?sc_bw=1&fo={GUID}&ro={GUID}` but so far I can only make one tree show up. Is it possible to have two trees displayed using this?

Comment: You can manage this by creating custom Roles as well.

Comment: You should use role based access to achieve the same instead of trying to create a custom Content Editor. Based on roles, users will see parts of Sitecore content tree - https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/92/platform-administration-and-architecture/create-and-set-up-a-role.html

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible through `Sitecore roles`.

1. Create a new Role in `Role Manager`
2. Inherit "`Sitecore Client Users`" and "`Sitecore Client Authoring Roles`" into the new role created in step1.

**Sitecore Client Users** role allows the user to login into the Sitecore portal.

**Sitecore Client Authoring** role will provide basic authoring access to the content and media items.

3. Once the role is created, apply the newly created role to the user.
4. Verify the changes by logging into the Sitecore with user mapped with new role, now you are able to see only Content, Form and Media Library Nodes.

Note: **Sitecore Client Authoring** role by default inherits from Author and Forms Editor Roles, if you want to disable Form editing you can explicitly deny read access to forms in your new Role.

Also, you can add few more other roles to provide publishing access etc..,